# La mejora manera de subir video utilizando ApiRest - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, laravel-4

Estoy intentando subir videos a mi plataforma estilo cursos. Mi problema es que los videos llegan a tardar bastante en subirse, y como sabrán, se debe notificar al frontend qué es lo que esta ocurriendo. He creado un pequeño código con el cual partir este dilema.

Mi controlador esta de la siguiente manera:

```
public function video(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('video');
    $storage = Storage::disk('public')->put('files/video' , $file);
 }
```

con el cual no tengo ningún problema, mi archivo se sube satisfactoriamente. 
Como seria para crear un progress que este notificando al frontend ó a caso hay algún paquete que pueda ayudar a mejorar el rendimiento de esto?.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes hacer una subida de este tipo si quieres feedback.

Tienes que crear un Job que te informe cuando acabe como muestra la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#creating-jobs) y estar esperando la respuesta con un socket (socket.io, redis, predis,...) si la necesitas usar el la visa

```
class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $podcast;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  Podcast  $podcast
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Podcast $podcast)
    {
        $this->podcast = $podcast;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @param  AudioProcessor  $processor
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(AudioProcessor $processor)
    {
        // Process uploaded podcast...
    }
}
```